# Add Already Existing Static framework to cocoapods

Tags: ios, static, frameworks, cocoapods

I have existing static framework.
Now I want it to be available through cocopods as well.
I am following [this](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-your-first-cocoapod--cms-24332) tutorial.

My pod File:

```
    #
# Be sure to run `pod lib lint MyiOSSDKFramework.podspec' to ensure this is a
# valid spec before submitting.
#
# Any lines starting with a # are optional, but their use is encouraged
# To learn more about a Podspec see http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html
#

Pod::Spec.new do |s|
s.name             = 'MyiOSSDKFramework'
s.version          = '2.0.0'
s.summary          = 'The MyiOSSDKFramework helps you create apps quickly and effortlessly.
# This description is used to generate tags and improve search results.
#   * Think: What does it do? Why did you write it? What is the focus?
#   * Try to keep it short, snappy and to the point.
#   * Write the description between the DESC delimiters below.
#   * Finally, don't worry about the indent, CocoaPods strips it!

s.description      = <<-DESC
TODO: SDK description will go here.
DESC

s.homepage         = 'https://github.com/xyz/MyiOSSDKFramework'
s.license          = { :type => 'MIT', :file => 'LICENSE' }
s.author           = { 'Priyanka Mistry' => 'priyanka.mistry@xyz.com' }
s.source           = { :git => 'https://github.com/xyz/MyiOSSDKFramework.git', :tag => s.version.to_s }
s.social_media_url = 'https://twitter.com/Myio'

s.ios.deployment_target = '7.0'
# s.source_files = 'MyiOSSDKFramework/Classes/*.{h,m}'
s.ios.vendored_frameworks = 'MyIOSDK/MyIO.framework'
s.resources = 'MyIOSDK/MyIO.bundle'

s.frameworks = 'Accounts', 'CFNetwork', 'CoreData', 'CoreGraphics', 'CoreLocation', 'CoreTelephony', 'MobileCoreServices', 'QuartzCore', 'Security', 'Social', 'SystemConfiguration'
s.libraries = 'icucore', 'sqlite3'
s.pod_target_xcconfig = { 'OTHER_LDFLAGS' => '-lObjC' }

end
```

while running `pod lib lint MyiOSSDKFramework.podspec` it show successful validation.

but, `pod spec lint MyiOSSDKFramework.podspec` gives me 2 errors at `s.ios.vendored_frameworks` and `s.resources`.

Error Message:

```
 - ERROR | [iOS] file patterns: The `resources` pattern did not match any file.
    - ERROR | [iOS] file patterns: The `vendored_frameworks` pattern did not match any file.
```

My folder structure:

```
 - MyiOSSDKFramework.podspec  
 - MyIOSDK/ 
    - MyIO.framework  
    - MyIO.bundle
```

I can't figure out what is going wrong here.

Comment: duplicate comment from the answer - please ignore

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if these files exist in the repo at  :git => 'https://github.com/xyz/MyiOSSDKFramework.git', :tag => s.version.to_s

Comment: Hi, thanks for you response. Actually I have already published framework on git. It contains 3 files: MySDK.bundle, MySDK.framework, and .DS_Store files. I have created project using the link I have mentioned. But I cant pull repo as it shows me error.  and hence can't push any changes.

Comment: the credential problems will cause the podspec validation to fail as it cant check the source folders.